# New to Xcode, can't use cout, only std::cout works

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, std, cout

I'm not new to programming but I am new to C++ using Xcode as the IDE. I am not allowed to use cout << "hello"; to print, the compiler complains and only works when I use std:cout <<. What setting in Xcode should be fixed in order to get this working the way I'm supposed to write it for class? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Add `using std::cout;` somewhere close to the start of your program, after the `includes`.

Please avoid the temptation to use `using namespace std;`. It's really a bad habit. Just because you see other people doing it, doesn't make it right. See the FAQ: [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

(Or, of course, you could just get use to typing `std::cout`.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I fixed it. You can simply write the following after the `#include`:

```
using namespace std;
```